# Change Windows taskbar toolbars order (sequence) on Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, start-menu, toolbar

when I create new toolbar on my Windows XP taskbar, it always appears under the 'Language bar' (I have the start menu binded to the left of my screen). Is there a way to change the placement (order) of the newly created toolbar, so it'd for example follow the Quick Launch toolbar, which is right after the START button (START menu at the top)?
Glossary:
Taskbar - an entity that contains toolbars
Toolbar - i. e. a 'Quick Launch' toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the task bar and uncheck "lock the taskbar".  You should then be free to drag the toolbars around.  When you're done, go ahead and lock the task bar again so you don't accidentally move the toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

I knew about the 'Lock the taskbar' feature, but I couldn't find a switch to grab with the mouse to be able to actually move the taskbar. Finally, I accidently clicked just over the toolbar separator and the black cross with four arrows pointing N, S, W, E appeared. So the solution is to either click on the toolbar title or click just below / next to the toolbar separator, so the 'move' cursor appears. I've also found the 'True Launch Bar' program that can extend the 'Quick Launch' toolbar functionalities a lot. Unfortunately, the program is not free.